# Grouping by multiple columns

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am not sure if the title is misleading but I wasn't sure how to summarise this one.

I have a table in an SQL DB where a record exists as below:

[image]

I would like to display the measurement values of this item in a gridview as below:

[image]

I thought about selecting the target values to a list (and the same for the actual values) as below:

```
Dim cdc As New InternalCalibrationDataContext
Dim allTargetvalues = (From i In cdc.int_calibration_records
                       Where i.calibration_no = Request.QueryString(0) And
                       i.calibration_date = Request.QueryString(1)
                       Select i.measure1_target, i.measure2_target, i.measure3_target).ToList()
```

Then joining the lists together in some way although I am unsure of how I could join the lists or even if this is the correct approach to be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let me first say that `measure1_target`, `measure2_target`, etc. is almost always indicative of bad database design.  These should probably be in another table as the "many" end of a 1-to-many relationship with the table you posted.  So to answer one of your questions:  No, this is not the correct approach to be taking.

With the structure of your table in its current state, your best option is probably something like this:

```
Dim cdc As New InternalCalibrationDataContext

Dim allTargetValues As New List(Of Whatever)
For Each targetValue In (From i In cdc.int_calibration_records
                         Where i.calibration_no = Request.QueryString(0) AndAlso
                               i.calibration_date = Request.QueryString(1)
                         Select i)

    allTargetValues.Add(New Whatever With {.MeasureNumber = 1,
                                           .Target = targetValue.measure1_target,
                                           .Actual = targetValue.measure1_actual })


    allTargetValues.Add(New Whatever With {.MeasureNumber = 2,
                                           .Target = targetValue.measure2_target,
                                           .Actual = targetValue.measure2_actual })

    allTargetValues.Add(New Whatever With {.MeasureNumber = 3,
                                           .Target = targetValue.measure3_target,
                                           .Actual = targetValue.measure3_actual })

Next
```

The `Whatever` class would look like this:

```
Public Class Whatever
    Public Property MeasureNumber As Integer
    Public Property Target As Integer
    Public Property Actual As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Douglas, works great. If I'm being honest I designed the table myself and I have next to no experience with designing databases

Comment: Glad I could help.  You may want to look into Foreign Keys and next time you can divide this up into 2 tables, since you really have 2 separate entities (Calibration and Measurement, for example).